# SQL Query JOIN with 4 tables

Tags: mysql

Who can help me?

I have 4 tables **posts**, **users**, **users details** and **comments**.

Here is the strucutre:

**posts**

- id
- title
- description

**users**

- id
- username
- password

**users_details**

- id
- user_id
- avatar
- location

**comments**

- id
- post_id
- user_id
- parent
- comment
- posted

I have a query which i want to display comments on specific post.

This is what i written but avatar column it doesn't show any results. It seems i written it wrong on join or something.

```
SELECT comments.id as comment_id,
    comments.user_id as user_id,
    comments.post_id as post_id,
    comments.parent as parent,
    comments.comment as comment,
    comments.posted as posted,
    users_details.avatar as avatar,
    users.username as username
FROM `comments`
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = comments.user_id
    LEFT JOIN users_details ON users_details.user_id = users.id
    WHERE comments.post_id='60337'
ORDER BY posted ASC
```

Here is a screenshot of the table with results https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZxjT.png

I want to mention the avatar field it has a value for that user in users_details table so it should be displayed...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see user_id column in comments table in the design you have provided?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Ok, sorry i forgot to mention, but it is there. i will edit now.

Comment: Does this query return any data or return NULL --> Select Avatar from Users_Details where User_Id in (2,9212)

Comment: Yes, it's returning data for each user.

Comment: Then the only thing I'd guess is that the users.id and users_details.user_id is not matching

Comment: did you check your foreign key for each user to have a avatar

Comment: Run those queries and ensure the users are the same::>>> select * from users where id in (2,9212) and select * from users_details where user_id in (2,2912)

Comment: You are right, i had a problem while updating users_details table and user_id from users_details didn't matched with id from users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential reasons I could tell causing this issue.

**1. The users do not have an avatar.**

Try:  `Select Avatar from Users_Details where User_Id in (2,9212)` and make sure it returns some data.

**2. The Primary/Foreign key being used for joining the tables is not matching**

Run those queries below and ensure that they are returning the same users.

```
select * from users where id in (2,9212) 
select * from users_details where user_id in (2,2912)
```

Comment: #2 was the reason. I had a problem while updating users_details table and user_id from users_details didn't matched with id from users...

Comment: @alexfsk. Glad to help my friend.